# Parametrization of Contour $C$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, parametrization

For the function $f(z)=1$ $(z\in \mathbb{C})$ and C is an arbitrary contour from any fixed point ${z}_{1}$ to any fixed point ${z}_{2}$ in the $z$ plane. Use parametric representations for $C$ to evaluate $\int _{C}^{}f(z)dz$.

**Here is my solution:** Let ${z}_{1}$ and ${z}_{2}$  are two fixed point and $C$ is straight line. Then $z=(1-t){z}_{1}+t{z}_{2}$ where $t\in \left[0,1\right]$, from here $dz=-{z}_{1}dt+{z}_{2}dt$. Then we get

$\int _{{z}_{1}}^{{z}_{2}}f(z)dz=\int _{0}^{1}1({z}_{2}dt-{z}_{1}dt)=\int _{0}^{1}{z}_{2}dt-\int _{0}^{1}{z}_{1}dt={z}_{2}-{z}_{1}$

Hence,

$\int _{C}^{}f(z)dz=\int _{{z}_{1}}^{{z}_{2}}f(z)dz=\int _{{z}_{1}}^{{z}_{2}}1dz={z}_{2}-{z}_{1}$

Is that my solution right ? I feel that I'm missing something. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure $C$ is an arbitrary contour ? It does not have some "smoothness" property ?

Comment: book exercise said arbitrary

Comment: Not sure parametrization will help though. May be the book includes some "smoothness" into the word "contour".

Comment: Page 135 / Exercises 5  https://math.unice.fr/~nivoche/pdf/Brown-Churchill-Complex%20Variables%20and%20Application%208th%20edition.pdf

Comment: The book defines "A contour, or piecewise smooth arc, is an arc consisting of a finite number of smooth arcs joined end to end. Hence if $z(t)$ represents a contour, $z(t)$ is continuous, whereas its derivative $z'(t)$ is piecewise continuous".  So you need to prove your conclusion using a piecewise smooth curve going from $z_1$ to $z_2$.

Comment: I do not get it, sorry

Comment: If $C$ is parametrized by a $C^1$ function $\gamma$, you have a formula for $\int_C f(z) dz$.

Comment: I've already used that formula above

Comment: Yes but you supposed that $C$ was a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine but restricted to the case where $C$ is a staight line. You are asked to prove the result for an arbitrary contour.

According to the definition given in the comments, a contour $C$ is the concatenation of smooth curves $C_1,\dots,C_K$. The curve $C_k$ has endpoints $c_{k-1},c_{k}$ and is parametrized by the $C^1$ function $\gamma_i:[0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{C}$. In particular, $c_0 = z_1$ and $c_K = z_2$.

By the formula for countour integration, for each $C_k$:

$$\int_{C_k} f(z) dz = \int_0^1 f(\gamma_k(t)) \gamma_k'(t) dt.$$

For the specific case $f(z) =1$, it yields:

$$\int_{C_k} f(z) dz =\int_0^1 \gamma_k'(t) dt=\left[ \gamma_k (t)\right]_0^1=c_k-c_{k-1}.$$

The concatenation of the smooth curves $C_k$ to create $C$ leads to:

$$\int_C f(z) dz = \sum_{k=1}^K \int_{C_k}f(z) dz= \sum_{k=1}^Kc_k-c_{k-1}$$

This sum is telescopic, and we are left with, as wanted:

$$\int_C f(z) dz = c_K-c_0=z_2-z_1.$$

**Further note :** this shows that the countour integration of the constant function $1$ is path-independent, it only depends on the endpoints. This property is in fact a characterization of holomorphic functions, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386162/contour-integrals-in-complex-analysis-that-dont-use-a-closed-contour-do-we-ha). Holomorphic function is the complex equivalent of being derivable for real ones, so it can be seen as an extension of the fundamental theorem of calculus to the complex domain.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Are you satisfied with this answer ? @softglance

Comment: Actually I am little bit confused, we did not define of integral with summation definition but I think It’s okay

Comment: It is the concatenation of the smooth curves forming yhe contour that introduced the sum (Chales' relation). If the contour is made of a single smooth curve, there is no summation but this is not the definition of a contour according to your document. Have a look at equation 6 page 132, actually it is given there.

Comment: Oh I see , yes you are correct. I’ve missed that equation (6) . Thanks for the proof.

Comment: Good to hear it helped you. You should accept the answer if you think it answered your questio.

Comment: Can we define the interval [a,b] instead of [0,1]?

Comment: Yes of course. You can go from one another by a linear map.